# BUG en ultima actualización Windows 10 con VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript

Buenos días,

En la última actualización de Windows 10 he encontrado un bug en File System Object (FSO) en Visual Basic Script. (VBS).

Al parecer aunque cierres un fichero que hayas abierto con FSO, no se libera la memoria, por lo que si tu metes en un bucle revisar un log el uso de memoria del script crece hasta que se queda sin memoria.

Esto no pasa en Windows 7 ni en versiones anteriores de Windows 10 donde si se libera la memoria tras cerrar el fichero.

Ejemplo:

```
path="d:\LocalData\ps05448\Desktop\Prueba.txt"
Const FOR_READING = 1
pausado=0
Do Until pausado=1
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = oFso.OpenTextFile(path,FOR_READING)
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
 linea=file.ReadLine
 if InStr(linea,"Linea de salida") > 0 then
  pausado=1
 End if
Loop
file.close
set file = Nothing
set oFso = Nothing
Loop
```

Prueba.txt seria el fichero de log que se está supervisando, haced la prueba sin poner la cadena de salida.

¿Hay alguna solución?

Un Saludo.

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Si, actualizando windows.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque resultó siendo un BUG del sistema operativo, cuya solución se dió en una actualización